# Why does UIViewController's subclass's init method sometimes not loading same name nib file?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, nib, init

I know that UIViewController's designated initializer is

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
```

If you call `init`,according to the documentation it will load the class's same name nib file(if it exist).

But what I encounterd is that sometimes init does do everything right. But sometimes some UIViewController's subclass 's init method just don't load it's nib file. I create them using the same way(using Xcode's assistant to create a UIViewController subclass and it's associated nib file at the same time, so the file name should all be the same).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that if the class is UITableViewController's subclass, you must use - `(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`
to init from nib.

This is because UIViewController's designate initializer is:

`(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`

so if you use `init`,it would therefore call `(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` for you.

But UITableViewController's designate initializer is:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
```

using `init`on UITableViewController will call `initWithStyle` not `initWithNibName`